# How to speed up this VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

The excel file has 9 sheets. Each sheet has 1668 rows and 34 suppliers. I want to create 1 sheet which contains all the data. I know this way there will be duplicates, but that doesn't matter now. Is there any way to speed up the code? It takes eternity time to copy approximately 510.000 records.
(You can see the comments with my first attempt when I tried to do it with for loops, that wasn't a good idea.)

```
Sub goEasy()

Dim wsText As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wSum As Worksheet
Dim service As String
Dim supplier As String
Dim priceRange As String
Dim price As String
Dim Lrow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim a As Long, b As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
Set wSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

wsText = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each element In wsText
    'For i = 5 To LastRow
    a = 4
    b = 12

    Do While a < LastRow
        'For j = 13 To 47

        If a = LastRow Then
            a = 4
            Exit Do
        End If
        a = a + 1

        Do While b <= 47

            If b = 47 Then
                b = 12
                Exit Do
            End If

            b = b + 1
            Lrow = wSum.UsedRange.Rows(wSum.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1

            service = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, 1).Text
            supplier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(4, b).Text
            priceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(2, 1).Text
            price = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, b).Text

            wSum.Cells(Lrow, 1) = service
            wSum.Cells(Lrow, 2) = supplier
            wSum.Cells(Lrow, 3) = priceRange
            wSum.Cells(Lrow, 4) = price
            'Next j
        Loop

        'Next i
    Loop
Next element


End Sub
```

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity including best-practices. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: Does turning off automatic calculations and screenupdating help at all?

Comment: Thank you Ralph, I didn't know that.

Comment: the block `If a = LastRow Then` seems unnecessary as it will never be hit.  Unless you meant to have `Do While a <= LastRow`

Comment: If you don't mind having duplicates, and just want to copy all sheets to 1, why not use something like: element.Range("Put_your_Range_Here").Copy
    wSum.Range("modify_lastrow_from_previous_paste").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Isn't something as `Sheets("SheetToCopyFrom").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("RangeWhereYouWantData")` way easier?

Comment: @Marcel10 , Unfortunately no, because I want to assign every service to every supplier to know how much do they offer. For example A service 1,2,3,4,5... all supplier and price, then go to the next service and do the same.

Comment: Pull each sheet into a variant array and spit it back out where you need it. That's the fastest way I can think of. Looping through worksheets isn't going to be your best bet, but there should be no appreciable time difference between `Do...Loop` and `For....Next`.

Comment: instead of pasting each record to summary sheet, try gathering all of them in array. Then paste whole array to range. Redim array at the begining, when you access a and b. Repeat the same steps for all 9 sheets.

Comment: Also, it's hard to know the fastest way to do this with no specification of what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Furtermore, you can read the value of 'priceRange' once per sheet and 'service' once per loop of A and put these values to variables. 
It looks like you would like to achieve kind of DB table data structure - maybe there are some algoritms for data normalization already..

Comment: @Markos How can I add the 4 variable to an array in 1 row format? I mean the 4 variable should appear as 1 row

Comment: Have you thought about dividing the sheets up into two or more workbooks and then running the code on each of them simultaneously? It may be an awkward solution, but it could give you what you need faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. (not tested)
It consumes time to write value into a cell.  Keeping writing values into cells will make your VBA slow.
By array, you only write into cells once.  It will save a lot of time.

```
Sub goEasy()
    dim a as long, b as long, LastRow as long
    dim sht as worksheet, wSum as worksheet
    dim wsText as variant, element as variant, dAry as variant

    set sht = thisworkbook.worksheets(4)
    set wSum = Thisworkbook.worksheets("summary")
    wsText = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")

    LastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each element In wsText
        a = 5
        b = 13
        Do until a > LastRow    'For i = 5 To LastRow
            Do until b > 47    'For j = 13 To 47
                if not isarray(dAry) then
                    redim dAry(3, 0) as variant
                else
                    redim preserve dAry(3, ubound(dAry, 2) + 1) as variant
                end if

                With thisworkbook.Worksheets(element)
                    dAry(0, ubound(dAry,2)) = .Cells(a, 1).Text
                    dAry(1, ubound(dAry,2)) = .Cells(4, b).Text
                    dAry(2, ubound(dAry,2)) = .Cells(2, 1).Text
                    dAry(3, ubound(dAry,2)) = .Cells(a, b).Text
                End With
                b = b + 1    'Next j
            Loop
            b = 13
            a = a + 1    'Next i
        Loop
    Next element
    wSum.Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).offset(1).resize(ubound(dAry,2) + 1, ubound(dAry,1) + 1) = application.transpose(dAry)
End Sub
```

Comment: this is something I was tinking about - however I would not redim preserve in the loop. you know array dimension prior entering the loop - it's arr(3,lastRow * 47). Also, no need to read .Cells(2, 1).Text each time as it's constant for each record.

Comment: @Markos, Thanks for your suggestion.  I did not notice that the dimension is pre-determined.  There are `9` elements * `(LastRow - 5 + 1)` * `(47 - 13 + 1)`, so `redim dAry(3, 9 * (LastRow - 5 + 1)*(47 -13 + 1)) As Variant` at once.    But, I usually use `redim preserve` in my work because I do not want to set another index to tell which row in array to write.

Answer (score -2):

This should do it:

```
Sub goEasy()

Dim wsText As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wSum As Worksheet
Dim service As String
Dim supplier As String
Dim priceRange As String
Dim price As String
Dim Lrow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim a As Long, b As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
Set wSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

wsText = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each element In wsText
        'For i = 5 To LastRow
        a = 4
        b = 12
        Do While a < LastRow
            'For j = 13 To 47

            If a = LastRow Then
            a = 4
            Exit Do
            End If
            a = a + 1

            Do While b <= 47

            If b = 47 Then
            b = 12
            Exit Do
            End If

                b = b + 1
                Lrow = wSum.UsedRange.Rows(wSum.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1

                service = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, 1).Text
                supplier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(4, b).Text
                priceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(2, 1).Text
                price = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, b).Text

                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 1) = service
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 2) = supplier
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 3) = priceRange
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 4) = price
            'Next j
            Loop
        'Next i
        Loop
    Next element

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```